# Creating a New JMeter Test Purely in Java for Java Sampler

Tags: java, jmeter

I've created a JMeter Java request and copied the jar to ext directory (`apache-jmeter-3.1\lib\ext`).
I'm trying to run the test on a remote machine. From the GUI I'm able to configure and run the Java request.
Also able to invoke the test via Java code using the JMX file as below.

```
ClientJMeterEngine jmeter = new ClientJMeterEngine("myclient");
File file = new File(RemoteJmeterTest.class.getResource("/finalSample.jmx").getFile());
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("D:/Tools/apache-jmeter-3.1");

HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(file); 
jmeter.configure(testPlanTree); 
jmeter.runTest();
```

Now I want to creating a New JMeter Test Purely in Java. But I don't know how to configure the Java sampler.
I see example [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) pointing how to configure the HTTP Sampler.
Instead of HTTPSampler, I need to configure my Java Request.
Please assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example code to add a [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler which will execute [SleepTest](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java) will look like:

```
JavaSampler javaSampler = new JavaSampler();
javaSampler.setName("Java Request");
javaSampler.setClassname("org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.SleepTest");
Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
arguments.addArgument("SleepTime", "1000");
arguments.addArgument("SleepMask", "0x33F");
javaSampler.setArguments(arguments);
javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JavaSampler.class.getName());
javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, JavaTestSamplerGui.class.getName());
```

In case if you need execute your own class implementing [JavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html) interface just substitute the classname and provide your own arguments if needed.

Full code just in case:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.control.gui.JavaTestSamplerGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class JMeterFromScratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("C:/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:/jmeter");
        //JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // JMeter Test Plan
        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        // Java Request
        JavaSampler javaSampler = new JavaSampler();
        javaSampler.setName("Java Request");
        javaSampler.setClassname("org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.SleepTest");
        Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
        arguments.addArgument("SleepTime", "1000");
        arguments.addArgument("SleepMask", "0x33F");
        javaSampler.setArguments(arguments);
        javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JavaSampler.class.getName());
        javaSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, JavaTestSamplerGui.class.getName());


        // Loop Controller
        TestElement loopController = new LoopController();
        ((LoopController) loopController).setLoops(1);
        loopController.addTestElement(javaSampler);
        ((LoopController) loopController).setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        ((LoopController) loopController).initialize();

        // Thread Group

        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(((LoopController) loopController));
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        // Test Plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(javaSampler);


        // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream("test.jmx"));

        //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
        // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }


        // Store execution results into a .jtl file
        String logFile = "test.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        // Run Test Plan
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

        System.out.println("Test completed. See test.jtl file for results");
        System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at test.jmx");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for comprehensive information on different ways of running a JMeter test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I used `ClientJMeterEngine` to run it on my remote Jmeter server.

Comment: Hello, How to add "View Results Tree" in the Java code and see its output when run from java command-line?