# Creating a New JMeter Test Purely in Java ans save as valid *.jmx

Tags: java, jmeter

I follow methods introduced in the [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344726/creating-a-new-jmeter-test-purely-in-java-for-java-sampler) and then save the hashTree as follow:

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.jmx");
    SaveService.saveTree(hashTree, out);
```

But, JMeter fails to open the file:
[image]

Is it possible to save and restore created test?

---

In the other hand, there is [a project on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42844065/635891) to create and save test. How ever the result is not valid JMX file.

---

I compare created file with a simple JMeter valid test script. These attributes are not added:

```
guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan"
```

I add them manually and all error fixed?!

---

Test and GUI classes must set as properties in a test element. Here is part of AbstractJMeterGuiComponent :

```
    mc.setProperty(new StringProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, this.getClass().getName()));
    mc.setProperty(new StringProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, mc.getClass().getName()));
```

So, GUI and the core is tied to each other and there are some main configurations in GUI.

How to build a valid JMX whiteout know about GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to set the following properties:

- [TestElement.TEST_CLASS](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestElement.html#TEST_CLASS)
- [TestElement.GUI_CLASS](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestElement.html#GUI_CLASS)

If you omit them you will still be able to run the test using [JMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/JMeterEngine.html), however attempt to open the generated script in GUI will fail.

Here is an example Test Plan which contains a [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you can use it as a reference.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class JMeterFromJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String jmeterHome = "/path/to/your/jmeter/installation";


        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();


        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        examplecomSampler.setDomain("example.com");
        examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
        examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
        examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
        examplecomSampler.setName("Open example.com");
        examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);

        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jmx"));


    }
}
```

References:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code)